# GitLab CI: Hidden files not showing after artifact extraction

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, hidden-files

I'm encountering an issue with my GitLab CI pipeline where hidden files (files and directories starting with a dot, e.g., `.nvmrc`, `.release-template.yml`, etc.) are not being displayed in the output after extracting artifacts.

Here's an overview of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
stages:
  - download
  - validate

zip:
  stage: download
  script:
    - curl -L -H "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/6585/repository/archive?sha=62eb5672cbe3c880e8a0d711a9dd276eabd3eae9" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: hstb1863823" > output.zip
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - output.zip

validate:terraform:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - unzip -o output.zip
    - ls -a
    - mv -v terraform-release-template-*/* . ## this does not move files start dot(.)
    - ls
  dependencies:
    - zip
```

Despite the `ls -a` command being used to list all files, including hidden ones, the hidden files are not shown in the output. I can confirm that these files exist in the extracted directory.

**Specific issues:**

1. Hidden files are not displayed in the output after extraction.
2. The `mv` command seems to be excluding hidden files from moving to the root directory.

**Question:**

- How can I ensure that hidden files are correctly displayed in the output after extracting artifacts in GitLab CI?
- Is there a specific configuration or command I'm missing to include hidden files during the extraction process?

Any insights or recommendations on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's about `artifacts:untracked` because it ignores configuration in the repository’s .gitignore file.

If `untracked: false`, the artifacts WILL have ALL files, even though ignored by `.gitignore`. Or in other words, it will ignore the `.gitignore`.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsuntracked

Comment: Even though this answer lead me to the right result, I request an update as there is an error in the formulation. 
If `untracked: false`, the artifacts WILL have ALL files, even though ignored by .gitignore. Or in otherworse, it will ignore the .gitignore . 
The provided link in the original answer explains it properly.